# Firebase updating or deleting array of objects in a vue js app

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

In my Vue js application i am pushing data from firebase firestore collection in an array in the form of objects , to display in a table

```
export default{
created(){
const thisIns= this
let user = firebase.auth().currentUser
let Ref = firebase.firestore().collection('College')
Ref.get().then(snapshot=>{
  snapshot.forEach(doc=>{
  let id = doc.id
  Ref.doc(id).collection('Students').onSnapshot(function(snapshot){
      snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change){
           if(change.type==="added"){
          let obj = change.doc.data()
          thisIns.students.push(obj)

})
})
})
})
}
```

this students array is then displayed in a table . Now the problem is whenever an update is made in a  document containing student information , instead of changing the data in the array  it pushes the same document containing the updated values in the students array thus there is same student  more than once  , one with previous details and one with the updated details , this is  corrected only when the page is refreshed , same when any student document is deleted the page needs to be refreshed for deletion from the table/array. How can the updation / deletion be done without reloading the page so that the application does not increase number of reads ?

Comment: Clear out the `thisIns.students` array at the start of the ref listener

Comment: @Phil  you mean this ?
      snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change){ thisIns.students=[ ]
since i am updating this method by using a popup (in whic the student id is passed for updation reference) , during updation then array is cleared but the popup gives error  TypeError: Cannot read property '$el' of undefined